# Error in function clbuildprogram... (it returns -11)

Tags: opencl

I've created a bubble sort code. The clbuildprogram in the user function createProgram  is giving an error
My kernel looks like:

```
__kernel void sort_kernel(__global const float *a, __global const float *b)
{
    const int n=100;
    int j;
    float temp;
    int gid = get_global_id(0);
    b[gid]=a[gid];

    for(j=0; j < n-gid; j++)
    {
        if(b[j+1]<b[j])
        {
            temp=b[j];
            b[j]=b[j+1];
            b[j+1]=temp;
        }
    }
}
```

clbuildprogram is giving an error as per the runtime error.

> ***Error in kernel: :1:1: error: unknown type name '_kernel'
>
> _kernel void sort_kernel(__global const float *a, __global const float *b) //, ^
>
> :1:9: error: expected identifier or '('
>   _kernel void sort_kernel(__global const float *a, __global const float *b) //,
>           ^
>
> :21:3: error: expected external declaration
>            }
>            ^
>
> :23:1: error: expected external declaration } ^
>
> :23:1: error: expected external declaration***

Please tell me what is the error and how can I rectify it...?

Comment: Are you really sure your kernel code starts with `__kernel` and not `_kernel` ? That is the error the JIT compiler is returning...

Comment: As for understanding and addressing compiler errors... always correct the very first one, ignoring the others, and then try again until it works. Especially in C and C++ dialects, one small typo tends to cascade into lots (hundreds in big projects) of incomprehensible and intimidating error messages. Only the first one is meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed a `_` in your program. The error is obvious.I dont think the code pasted here is the same as you run.
Correct your `_kernel` to `__kernel` in your program.